# Given a correlation matrix, how to get a partition depending on whether the variables are correlated or not for an arbitrary threshold?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

Given a correlation matrix, how to let R returns a partition depending on whether the variables are correlated (connected) or not for an arbitrary threshold?

For example, staring by:

```
corr(x)
```

and find partitions defined by:

```
corr(x) > 0.5
```

return row / column names grouped as a list of characters.

```
list(c("a", "b"), "d")
```

means that "a", "b" are in one group but not "d".

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with dput() and use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) and show your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The question is currently not very detailed so I am unsure whether this solves your problem, however here is my suggestion to produce a list of all pairs of a correlation matrix above a specific threshold:

```r
# example dataset
a <- mvtnorm::rmvnorm(10,rep(0,10)) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(LETTERS[1:10])

# correlation matrix
ca <- cor(a)
# optional: remove upper.tri and diag to avoid duplicates
ca[upper.tri(ca,T)] <- NA

# matrix of name pairs corresponding to each cell of ca
cm <- do.call(expand.grid, dimnames(ca)) |>
  apply(1,c,simplify = F) |>
  lapply(unname) |>
  matrix(ncol(ca))

# use the correlation matrix to filter the matrix of name pairs
# may remove abs() to obtain only positive correlations
cutoff <- .4
as.list(cm[!is.na(ca)&abs(ca)>cutoff])
```

**EDIT: actual partitioning into groups of correlated variables**

```r
# correlation matrix
cb <- cor(a)
# optional: heatmap of the correlation matrix to get an impression of clusters
# heatmap(cb)
# adjustable cut-off
cutoff <- 0.4
# partitioning using 1-pearson correlation as distance
hc <- hclust(as.dist(1-cb))
# optional: plot hierarchical partitioning tree to see the grouping
# plot(hc)
# cut the tree at 1-cutoff, to apply the required threshold
ct <- cutree(hc,h = 1-cutoff)
# obtain the list of partitions
lapply(unique(ct),\(x) {
  names(ct)[ct==x]
})
```

The combined use of 1-correlation as distance and 1-cutoff as threshold ensures that the partitions relate to the (Pearson) correlation coefficient in the specified way.

Answer (score 0):

You may add an inverted correlation matrix, obtained by adding `-1`, in an `lapply`, then `list` complementary elements with `Reduce`.

Consider this small subset of `mtcars`

```
> m
       mpg   cyl  disp
mpg   TRUE FALSE FALSE
cyl  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
disp FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> lapply(c(0, -1), \(x) apply(`mode<-`(abs(m + x), 'logical'), 1, \(x) names(which(x)))) |>
+   Reduce(function(...) Map(list, ...), x=_)
$mpg
$mpg[[1]]
[1] "mpg"

$mpg[[2]]
[1] "cyl"  "disp"


$cyl
$cyl[[1]]
[1] "cyl"  "disp"

$cyl[[2]]
[1] "mpg"


$disp
$disp[[1]]
[1] "cyl"  "disp"

$disp[[2]]
[1] "mpg"
```

---

*Data:*

```
> m <- cor(mtcars[, 1:3]) > .5
```

Comment: this gives a list of lists rather than just one list indicating the groups. Also it wont work in other examples. eg `p <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1), 5)`

Answer (score 0):

use `igraph`

```
m <- cor(mtcars[, 1:3]) > .5
split(colnames(m), igraph::components(igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m))$membership)
$`1`
[1] "mpg"

$`2`
[1] "cyl"  "disp"
```