# How can I find all the mutually correlated rows of a correlation matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I created a sample matrix and computed the pairwise correlations of the rows using the following code:

```
mtx <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:8,function(x) {
  set.seed(x)
  runif(15)
}))
dimnames(mtx) <- list(paste0("r",as.character(1:nrow(mtx))),paste0("s",as.character(1:ncol(mtx))))
cor_mtx <- cor(t(mtx),use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

My goal is to return all rows that are mutually correlated above a certain threshold. Let's say my threshold is 0.2. With the above generated matrix, you can see that r1 is correlated with r5 and r8 above this threshold. r5 and r8 are also correlated with each other above the threshold. Thus all 3 should be returned together. How can I programmatically return the mutually correlated row modules? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How far should the clustering go? E.g. `r7--r2` and `r2--r3` and `r3--r8` and `r8--r6` etc... until they are all in the same cluster ultimately. (If I change the cutoff to 0.4, it becomes less connected, with two distinct groups).

Comment: The largest mutually correlated set would be ideal. And in the case of same sizes, returning the set with the highest mean correlation

Comment: more solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77634295/given-a-correlation-matrix-how-to-get-a-partition-depending-on-whether-the-vari/77635750#77635750

Answer (score 2):

Using `igraph::max_cliques` we can see there are 4 cliques of size 2 and one clique of size 3 (r1, r5, and r8):

```
library(igraph)

max_cliques(graph_from_adjacency_matrix((cor_mtx > 0.2), "undirected"), 2)
#> [[1]]
#> + 2/8 vertices, named, from 904d6ab:
#> [1] r7 r2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> + 2/8 vertices, named, from 904d6ab:
#> [1] r3 r2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> + 2/8 vertices, named, from 904d6ab:
#> [1] r4 r8
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> + 2/8 vertices, named, from 904d6ab:
#> [1] r2 r8
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> + 3/8 vertices, named, from 904d6ab:
#> [1] r8 r1 r5
```

---

From the comments:

> The largest mutually correlated set would be ideal. And in the case of
> same sizes, returning the set with the highest mean correlation

```
cl <- cl[lengths(cl) == max(lengths(cl))]
cl <- if (length(cl) > 1) {
  cl[which.max(sapply(cl, \(x) sum(cor_mtx[x, x])))]
} else cl[[1]]

cl
#> + 3/8 vertices, named, from f733f6f:
#> [1] r8 r1 r5
```

Comment: Interesting. I will have to read up on what a *clique* exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but using *igraph* to do the clustering/grouping of correlations gives a sensible result to my mind.
(I've adjusted the cutoff to 0.4 to make it clearer what the results will be):

```
sel <- abs(cor_mtx) > 0.4
diag(sel) <- FALSE
##      r1    r2    r3    r4    r5    r6    r7    r8
##r1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##r2 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##r3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##r4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##r5 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
##r6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
##r7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##r8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

out <- expand.grid(dimnames(cor_mtx))[sel,]

library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(out)
cmp <- components(g)$membership
split(names(cmp), cmp)
##$`1`
##[1] "r3" "r2"
##
##$`2`
##[1] "r8" "r5" "r6"
```